# WinApi - Iterate Over All Resources In Module As Quick As Possible?

Tags: performance, winapi, resources

I have an executable file that contains resources. I want them to be read from the same executable. The resource structure looks like this (viewing with Resource Hacker):

- TEXT

  - TEXT0

    - 0
  - TEXT1

    - 0
  - TEXT3

    - 0
  - TEXT4

    - 0

---

I would start like this:

```
IntPtr handle = LoadLibrary("filename.exe");
IntPtr[] res = new IntPtr[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    res[i] = FindResource(handle, "TEXT" + i, "TEXT");
```

I will have **A LOT** of those resources. I can imagine that this will become very slow later because `FindResource` suggests that there is a search going on for each item. How can I iterate over them very quick ? If I could get a list out of the module ...

Is `FindResource` the best way to go ?

Comment: How "quick" is your current code? How "quick" does it need to be?

Comment: Can't tell right now. But if `EnmuResource...` can be more performant I don't want to develop in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

[`EnumResourceNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`EnumResourceTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`EnumResourceLanguages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be useful here.